# PHP - Strings and Integers

Tags: php

My site uses PHP to check if the value submitted by the user using the "get" method is a certain integer. The code is something along the lines of

```
if ($_GET['input']==2) { ... }
```

However I have recently discovered that if the user inputs something like `2a`, `2two` or even `2omdodonsos`, it is still perceived as the value `2` by PHP. However if the user inputs `23eee`, `23twenty` or `23ofnofnonf`, it is not perceived as `2`. Why does this happen? Will using this code:

```
 if ($_GET['input']="2") { ... }
```

solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can (and should) use [input filtering](http://www.php.net/filter) to weed out the bad input:

```
if (is_null($input = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'input', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE))) {
    // an entry that was not an integer
} elseif ($input === 2) {
    // input was 2
}
```

See also: [`filter_input()`](http://www.php.net/filter_input)

Comment: PHPs filter functions are underused. Shame, they're good. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

For an explanation why this happens, read the documentation on [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

The solution is a type safe comparison (`===`)

```
$_GET['input'] === '2'
```

Comment: Additionally, `(int)sprintf('%d', $_GET['input'])` could make sure you're working with a clean number. It will return `0` if the input variable couldnt be parsed into a decimal number.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast: this should be functionally equivalent to `intval($_GET['input'])` or `(int)$_GET['input']`. The `sprintf` is redundant. Of course it only becomes relevant as soon as the input will be used in other places than the "equals 2" check.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the GET value is numeric and then compare it with number 2:

```
if (is_numeric($_GET['input']) ) {
    switch($_GET['input']) {
      case 1:
      case 2:
       // write your code here
      break;
      default:
       //Default option
     }
 }
```

OR use directly === comparison operator as @fab suggested.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php